# How can I efficiently find lists of cognates and false friends?

Tags: resource-request, vocabulary

I'm referring to cognates and false friends of two languages. Books list some of them, but usually not exhaustively.

Comment: Are you interested in this just for fun, or as part of actually studying a language? If it's the latter, I feel like learning from lists is less effective than learning from context - books, movies, music, etc. As for cognates, this could be a *very* long list depending on how close the two languages are. You can use [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) to understand the origin of individual words, and their cognates in other languages.

Comment: @RuslanD "Are you interested in this just for fun, or as part of actually studying a language?" Both.